# Minmax problem for polygons

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, plane-geometry

Let $\text{Pol}_n$ be the set of all convex polygons on a plane with $n$ vertices. For $P\in \text{Pol}_n$ denote by $\text{Tr}(P)$ the set of all triangles which vertices are some vertices of $P$. I want to find an explicit formula for the function
$$
\Phi(n)=\inf\limits_{P\in \text{Pol}_n}\max\limits_{T\in \text{Tr}(p)}\frac{\text{area}(T)}{\text{area}(P)}
$$
It is not hard to prove that $\Phi(3)=1$, $\Phi(4)=1/2$. For $n\geq 5$ we have an estimation $\Phi(n)\geq 1/(n-2)$.

Here you can find [some attempts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90715/minmax-problem-for-polygons) to solve it. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Somewhat related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34865/elementary-problem-about-triangles-inside-a-convex-polygon

Comment: An algorithm for finding a maximal triangle is given in http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~sityon/soda06.pdf. I don't know whether the paper, or its references, contains any theoretical results on the size of said triangle. 